# Let Last exceptions from Last powershell execution only

Tags: exception, powershell

I need to print some exception onto screen/Log in file.

Is there a way to get all exceptions that resulted from last script execution only ?
Consider this as an example :

- I open a powershell window
- I exceute abc.ps1 , it throws some error.
- I execute now xyz.ps1 which throws more than one exception. Now I want to log all exception from xyz.ps1 only.

If i use `$error[0]`, I get only last exception . I need other exceptions that were thrown by xyz.ps1 as well

Comment: You should consider instead implementing proper error handling using try/catch

Comment: what Noah said if you need to catch specific errors in a script use try catch to get them and log them.

Comment: Noah and Dane i understand best way is to capture specific exceptions in try catch blocks, but problem is we have lot number of powershells and are already written , so i was just trying have logging in a way that i talked above. Catch all exceptions resulting from wrapper powershell scripts(and underlying cmdlets,scripts) and log them in a file.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have come up with the way to do this. If you inspect the properties of $error[0] with `Get-Member` cmdlet (`$error[0] | Get-Member`) you should notice a property called `ScriptStackTrace`. This property tells us if the error was raised from a script or from console. With the following code I managed to achieve what you ask for:

```
for ($i=0;$i -lt $error.Count; $i++) 
{ if ($Error[$i].ScriptStackTrace -match "xyz.ps1") 
{ $error[$i] | out-file -Append "ErrorsScriptXYZ.txt" } }
```

If you intend to use the script in a callable way, add this as the last line of execution. Note that it will not catch terminating errors that could occur before the script operates. Explore the `Get-Member` cmdlet for more properties that you wish to manipulate on. Note that this will only search for errors in the current variable session, as the errors are gone on the next startup.